# How to filter JSON object

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON object that is a list of Students that have Name, FName, City, Class, Contact.
Now I want to filter only the objects (Students) which belong to the specific city. Can I filter the mail json object

```
{
  "Students": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "Name": "Student1",
      "FName": "FName1",
      "Class": "I",
      "City": "Delhi"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "Name": "Student2",
      "FName": "FName2",
      "Class": "II",
      "City": "Mumbai"
    },
     {
      "id": 3,
      "Name": "Student3",
      "FName": "FName3",
      "Class": "II",
      "City": "Delhi"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "Name": "Student4",
      "FName": "FName4",
      "Class": "III",
      "City": "Mumbai"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get sub json list of students belongs to Delhi City?

Comment: All you can do is parse the object, compare `City` and get the object.

Comment: Iterate over and check for specified city, if city matches put it in separate JSON.

Comment: You mean, we can no query on the json object to get sub json object set. Is it ?

Comment: You can with JSONPath: https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

Comment: You can try this: http://danski.github.io/spahql/

Answer (score 6):

Using [JSONPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) the selection would look like this:

```
JsonPath.read(jsonAsString, "$.Students[?(@.City==Delhi)]")
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Java 8 the following works (note: I am using Jackson, but as long as your JSON library returns a Map object for JSON objects, this example will still work):

```
// These 2 lines are Jackson specific    
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map obj = mapper.readValue(s, Map.class);

List<Object> students = (List<Object>) obj.get("Students");
Object[] delhiStudents = students
    .stream()
    .filter(student -> ((Map)student).get("City").equals("Delhi"))
    .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot play around much with available `Json library`, all you can do is to convert it into some `POJO` or say `Map`. refer [this](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/11/json-to-hashmap-parsing-json-string.html)

Also i found something [here](http://www.quora.com/Davina-May/Data-process-and-programming-language/esProc-Helps-Process-Heterogeneous-Data-Sources-in-Java-JSON) as well. It might help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a third-party library, you can use [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/). What you have to do is providing a custom deserializer to the Gson object. This deserializer will exclude all the Students objects that have the specific city value in their JSON representation.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        Type type = new TypeToken<List<Student>>() {}.getType();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().registerTypeAdapter(type, new Student.StudentListDeserializer("Mumbai")).create();
        List<Student> list = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("myJson.json"), type);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}

class Student {
    private long id;
    private String Name;
    private String FName;
    private String Class;
    private String City;


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", Name=" + Name + ", FName=" + FName
                + ", Class=" + Class + ", City=" + City + "]";
    }

    static class StudentListDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<List<Student>>{

        private Set<String> forbiddenCities;

        public StudentListDeserializer(String... forbiddenCities) {
            this.forbiddenCities = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(forbiddenCities));
        }

        @Override
        public List<Student> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
        JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
            List<Student> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for(JsonElement e : json.getAsJsonObject().get("Students").getAsJsonArray()) {
                if(!forbiddenCities.contains(e.getAsJsonObject().get("City").getAsString())) {
                    list.add(context.deserialize(e, Student.class));
                }
            }
            return list;
         }               
     }        
}
```

which outputs:

```
[Student [id=1, Name=Student1, FName=FName1, Class=I, City=Delhi], Student [id=3, Name=Student3, FName=FName3, Class=II, City=Delhi]]
```

Comment: Will this provide a better performance than I iterate and filter on list of Student objects? Under compulsion i have to o in Java 7

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DSM](https://mfatihercik.github.io/dsm) library. By using it you can filter JSON while you reading JSON data.

Let's say you have POJO class for the student. Fields of student are not exactly matched with JSON data.

**Student Class**

```
public class Student {
    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String firstName;
    private String className;
    private String city;

 // getter/setter

}
```

You will define a yaml file that contains definitions of your mappings between json and Student class.

```
result:
  type: array     # result is list 
  path: /Students
  filter: self.data.city=='Delhi'   # filter by city field of class
  fields:
    id: long      # id is long and path is the same as json id field.
    name:
      path: Name
    firstName:
      path: FName
    className:
      path: Class
    city:
      path: City
```

Use DSM to **filter JSON and deserialize** to **Student** class

```
DSM dsm=new DSMBuilder(new File("student.yaml")).create(Student.class);
List<Student> students= (List<Student>)dsm.toObject(new File("student.json");
```

Here is **students** list that converted to json.

```
[ {
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Student1",
  "className" : "I",
  "city" : "Delhi",
  "firstName" : "FName1"
}, {
  "id" : 3,
  "name" : "Student3",
  "className" : "II",
  "city" : "Delhi",
  "firstName" : "FName3"
} ]
```