# Extract Json nested objects under a specific path using inputstream in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, stream, iterator

Have been searching this for a while, and I've also developed something working but wondering if there is a framework that can make my life easier.

The problem is simple, I have a Json InputStream representing a really large data payload.

I know for sure that this payload contains an array of objects under a known path, and I do not want to parse the stream in memory, instead I would like to `seek` on the file on the given path and extract all the objects of the nested array one at a a time as a `Map<String,Object>`.

Example:

```
{
   "store": {
      "book" : [

         {
           "isbn": "123",
           "author": "author",
           "title": "title",
         },
         ..... many more objects
      ]
   }
}
```

What I need is to `seek` on `$.store.book` and extract individual nested objects for further processing.

I've tried `JsonPath (jayway)` but the parse method seem to load everything in memory.

I've then used Jackson with the stream library but the solution that I got is a bit convoluted. Is there an easier way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: what do want to extract exactly ? and what do you want to do with that?

Comment: Is it relevant what I want to do next ?
I just want to get a map of String Object that represents the ith element in that array without loading everything into memory

Comment: It's relevant, You are going to load it into memory if you want to filter it. It might be a load of each element and discard, but its a load to memory regardless. 

I added a stream implementation as an answer below.

Comment: Yes you are right in this case I do not need to filter it out but convert and write them out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the JSON array you're interested in can be identified by a JSON pointer, then a [FilteringParserDelegate](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/filter/FilteringParserDelegate.html) with a [JsonPointerBasedFilter](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/filter/JsonPointerBasedFilter.html) can do the job. This is basically a streaming parser that skips ahead until the target is found. Then you can continue streaming the interesting tokens, or do data binding.

```
private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
private static final JsonFactory factory = mapper.getFactory();

public static void processArrayElements(InputStream json, 
                                        JsonPointer pointerToArray,
                                        Consumer<Map<String, Object>> consumer)
    throws IOException {

  JsonParser parser = new FilteringParserDelegate(
      factory.createParser(json),
      new JsonPointerBasedFilter(pointerToArray), false, false);

  if (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
    throw new IOException("Expected an array but found " + parser.currentToken());
  }

  while (parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
    consumer.accept(parser.readValueAs(Map.class));
  }
}
```

To print the books:

```
JsonPointer bookArray = JsonPointer.compile("/store/book");
processArrayElements(json, bookArray, System.out::println);
```

Comment: Updated to allow processing just one book at a time instead of keeping the whole array in memory.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, my version was essentially re implementing this but this is a much more concise way of addressing the problem.

On a separate side, and a bit out of topic, is there a way to force the object mapper deserialisation to always coerce all numbers to string ? I've tried different config options but nothing works

Comment: @user2151096 Glad to help. Jackson will coerce numbers to Strings when biding to a Java object (for example, if you deserialized to a Book class instead of a Map). I'm not aware of an easy way to configure Jackson to deserialize numbers as Strings when deserializing to a Map or to the tree model.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to sequentially look through the data at a limited rate such as 512 or 1024 bytes at a time. You could then parse the bytes to the encoded format which is likely ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8. You could then read all bytes until some delimiter is met, likely `]` to signify the end of the array (hopefully). You could then use Jackson or Gson to load just that array of objects.

Comment: Well this is even more convoluted than just using the Jackson streaming API I guess

Answer (score 0):

You need `ParamTOFilterBy` and `FilterValue`

If you insist on Using [JSONPath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) the selection would look like this:

```
JsonPath.read(jsonAsString, "$.store.book[?(@.ParamTOFilterBy==FilterValue)]")
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27420014/how-to-filter-json-object/27420276#27420276) talks about filtering a JSON String. **Opinion** I like Jackson implementation in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27424214/1684254)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution reads all objects in memory

Comment: Couldn't you just filter it at the source? Create another endpoint?

Comment: the source is a stream itself like a file in s3

Comment: Look at the third answer in that question.