# Deserialize only 1 JSON object from JSON array

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to deserialize the below json and would like to have only the necessary fields in the result.
Is it possible to extract only the **"DD"** field from the **commonfeed** array with gson or some other way? Replacing **`@SerializedName("DD")`** with other mechanism perhaps?

```
String json = "{\"common_feed\": [{\"DA\": 1}, {\"DZ\": 1}, {\"DB\": 1}, {\"DD\": 1641585600}, {\"DM\": \"\"}, {\"POS\": false}, {\"DX\": \"OD,HH,SCR,LT,TA,TV\"}, {\"DT\": false}], \"final_stage\": \"\", \"participantsData\": {\"home\": [{\"id\": \"YeGlkuUb\", \"name\": \"Mlada Boleslav\"}], \"away\": [{\"id\": \"rgfiJkOs\", \"name\": \"Litvinov\"}], \"is_national\": false}}";
            final Result result = new GsonBuilder()
                    .serializeNulls()
                    .create()
                    .fromJson(json, Result.class);
System.out.println(result);


    class Result {
        ParticipantsData participantsData;
        @SerializedName("common_feed")
        List<CommonFeed> commonFeed;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Result{" +
                    "participantsData=" + participantsData +
                    ", commonFeed=" + commonFeed +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    class ParticipantsData {
        List<Team> home;
        List<Team> away;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ParticipantsData{" +
                    "home=" + home +
                    ", away=" + away +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    class Team {
        String name;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Team{" +
                    "name='" + name + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    class CommonFeed {
        @SerializedName("DD")
        int date;

        public CommonFeed(int date) {
            this.date = date;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "CommonFeed{" +
                    "date=" + date +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

output:

```
Result{participantsData=ParticipantsData{home=[Team{name='Mlada Boleslav'}], away=[Team{name='Litvinov'}]}, commonFeed=[CommonFeed{date=0}, CommonFeed{date=0}, CommonFeed{date=0}, CommonFeed{date=1641585600}, CommonFeed{date=0}, CommonFeed{date=0}, CommonFeed{date=0}, CommonFeed{date=0}]}
```

desired output:

```
Result{participantsData=ParticipantsData{home=[Team{name='Mlada Boleslav'}], away=[Team{name='Litvinov'}]}, commonFeed=[CommonFeed{date=1641585600}]}
```

Comment: As far as I understand you may wat something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27424214/10832295

Comment: Not possible because Gson deserializes everything it can. Deserialize the list first, then filter it with a predicate where the `DD` mapping is not null. If it takes too much memory, implement your own stream reader pulling only what you need. It looks like a sign a bad design anyway.

Comment: thank you for both of your suggestions. 
@fluffy - however, I've implemented yours.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing beats a good design. But if really necessary, in addition to what commented you can trick GSON while deserializing with a type of your own. So for example creating class like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CommonFeedList extends ArrayList<CommonFeed> {
    @Override
    public boolean add(CommonFeed commonFeed) {
        if(commonFeed.getDate() == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        return super.add(commonFeed);
    }
}
```

and with a little modification to your `Response` class:

```
class Result {        
    @SerializedName("common_feed")
    CommonFeedList commonFeed;
    ...
}
```

The con of course is that changing the list type also prevents to serialize nothing else than "DD type" of `CommonFeed`. In that case you need another type to serialize all types.

Anyway this kind of stuff should not be used carelessly. Always check the possibility to change the design first.